# SQL statement not producing any results

Tags: php, sql, syntax, syntax-error

```
SELECT 
    ID AS Employee_Name,
    department AS Employee_Department,
    business_unit AS Employee_Business,
    SUM(hours_used) Employee_Hours
FROM 
    TableX
WHERE
    Day_Used BETWEEN 04/01/2014 AND 04/30/2014
GROUP BY
    department
```

This is my current SQL statement, and what I'm trying to do is get output from the database however I have not been successful and maybe you guys can point out why.

The goal is to SUM all employee hours by department, and group them by department between the given dates. I know my statement would not display that information as of right now, I am currently just trying to figure out why I can't get any output.

Thanks for your time!

**EDIT:** Here is a simpler test query that works with the SUM(hours_used) working correctly.

```
   SELECT
       ID AS Employee_Name,
       SUM(hours_used) AS Employee_Hours
   FROM
       TableX
   WHERE
       Day_Used BETWEEN 04/01/2014 AND 04/30/2014
   GROUP BY
       ID
```

I am very grateful for all of your feedback! This is what my original SQL problem looks like so far. I just need to figure out how to get it to SUM(hours_used) by department. (**IE:** Ted has 15 hours for accounting and 10 hours for companyX)

```
SELECT 
    ID AS Employee_Name,
    department AS Employee_Department,
    business_unit AS Employee_Business,
    SUM(hours_used) AS Employee_Hours
FROM 
    TableX
WHERE
    Day_Used BETWEEN '04/01/2014' AND '04/30/2014'
GROUP BY
    ID, department, business_unit, hours_used
```

Pecci inadvertently solved my last problem! I just had to remove hours_used in my GROUP BY and everything displayed as it should! I'd like to give a HUGE thank you to everyone who helped solve my problem, thanks so much!!!

Comment: how about `Day_Used BETWEEN '04/01/2014' AND '04/30/2014'` ?

Comment: That was quick, also thanks for the formatting help, I just noticed and was about to fix that myself. Just tried quotes around the dates and that didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Those aren't dates they are string representations of dates. Try `2014-04-30`.

Comment: hmm @AbraCadaver good point what is the data type of your date and which format they are saved?

Comment: The data type would be DATE, however the way this table was formatted by its owner was mm/dd/yyyy.

Comment: you mean in DB also its saved in mm/dd/yyyy format using DATE data type ? thats weird

Comment: Exactly. Now I've noticed that the hours_used column is a REAL data type, could that impact the sum function causing me to error out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have all of your fields in an aggregate function or the group by statement.

```
SELECT 
    ID AS Employee_Name,
    department AS Employee_Department,
    business_unit AS Employee_Business,
    SUM(hours_used) Employee_Hours
FROM 
    TableX
WHERE
    Day_Used BETWEEN '04/01/2014' AND '04/30/2014'
GROUP BY
    ID,department,business_unit
```

The reason for adding the other columns as an aggregate [(SUM, COUNT, ETC)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx) or to the GROUP BY is because of how the data is being looked at.

Say you have the following table

```
ID   intValue  Color
1    1         Blue
2    2         Blue
3    5         Green
4    10        Red
5    15        Red
6    5         Blue
```

And I want to get a SUM of of all of the `intValue` by color.

I would want to first make sure to select both columns `SELECT intValue, Color FROM table1`

Now, since I want the sum of the intValue, I would add the aggregate function
`SELECT SUM(intValue), Color FROM table1`

Now, the issue you're having is here. Without telling the DBMS what you want to group by (The colors in this example) how else would it know? By adding a group by I tell it that I want to have the `SUM` of all intValue's where it has been grouped on `Color`. 
`SELECT SUM(intValue), Color FROM table`

By not doing either an aggregate or a group by on all of the column, the DBMS has no idea what to do with your query.

Comment: Could you elaborate for me a little bit as to why I need to add department and business_unit and why I couldn't just group by ID?

Comment: @user3216177 I have updated the answer with an explanation. Let me know if it is enough or id I should expand a bit more.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! That helped a lot. Now if I could just figure out what my problem is with SUM(hours_used). When I removed the "AS Employee_Hours" I suddenly got a table populated and the column name turned out to be "SUM(hours_used)" and nothing was summed up. Any thoughts on why that happened? **EDIT:** I goofed when testing some of the suggestions here and forgot to put "AS" back in. However it still doesn't seem to be adding up the hours by department for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

When you use SUM, COUNT... you need to put all the others columns in the group by.
Another thing to look is how the dates are stored in the db and if your are using the between correctly.

Comment: Indeed, I get results when I remove the SUM(hours_used) portion. When I add it back in, I get 0 output. Any ideas? Edit: I have added the missing GROUP BY columns, as well as the single quotes around the dates.

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: RBase, which I have minimal experience with (theoretically it shouldn't be too different, but I've had some issues unrelated to this project crop up before).

Comment: After all this changes i think there's a chance the problem may be the type of the column hours_used. Can you try another select and sum one column of type numeric? just a check...

Comment: I've updated my original post, let me know if this helps out at all!

Comment: Very nice...
You dont actually need the hours_used in the group by, just the itens besides the sum.

Comment: I think you just solved my problem! Thanks so much! :) Everyone here was extremely helpful and if I could upvote you guys I totally would!

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem are the date constants:

```
SELECT ID AS Employee_Name,
       department AS Employee_Department,
       business_unit AS Employee_Business,
       SUM(hours_used) as Employee_Hours
FROM TableX
WHERE Day_Used BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-30'
GROUP BY id, department, business_unit;
```

Most databases will recognize the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format for date constants.  Your specific database might have another preferred format, but the constant value does need to be between single quotes.